# date field value returning string instead of date

Tags: elasticsearch

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import json
import sys
from dateutil.parser import parse

# create instance of elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch('localhost:9200')

with open ('C:\\Users\\paul.braimoh\\Desktop\\infrastructure.json')as b:
    data = json.load(b)
    print(data)
print (data);

for key, value in enumerate(data):
    print(key, value)
    es.index(index="infrastructure2", doc_type="test-type", body=value)
```

And this is how the json file looked like

```
[
  {
    "Date": "1/1/2018",
    "Location": "location",
    "TYPE OF SOLUTION": "solution",
    "SLO": "90%",
    "Availability": "100.00%",
    "Comments": "resolve"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, when a previously unseen field is found in a document, Elasticsearch will add the new field to the type mapping. If `date_detection` is enabled ([default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html#date-detection)), then new string fields are checked to see whether their contents match any of the date patterns specified in dynamic_date_formats.

Another factor to consider is, [according to the client documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/index.html),

datetimes will be serialized

```
es.index(index="my-index", doc_type="test-type", id=42, body={"any": "data", "timestamp": datetime.now()})
{u'_id': u'42', u'_index': u'my-index', u'_type': u'test-type', u'_version': 1, u'ok': True}
```

but not deserialized

```
es.get(index="my-index", doc_type="test-type", id=42)['_source']
{u'any': u'data', u'timestamp': u'2013-05-12T19:45:31.804229'}
```

So you just need to parse the date with `datetime.strptime`

Comment: please how do I do that

Comment: `datetime.strptime(date_string, "%d/%m/%Y")` will return the `datetime` object. formats here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior